# France Visa Query

Tags: visas, france, schengen

I have a visa issued by the French embassy in UAE. It will expire on 8th June. Unfortunately my travel plans have changed and now I need to enter France on 10th June. Is it still possible that I enter France on 7th June and leave the country within 16 days as the visa validity is for 16 days.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  If your visa is not valid yet on the 7th you have no permission to be in Schengen area.

Comment: @Karlson From what I understood, the visa is valid on the 7th. The question he asks, I suppose, is whether the validity of the visa is 16 days after arrival date, or the visa expire date, or the earliest of these dates.

Comment: @Vince Misread it.  It's valid on 7th but expires on 8th.

Comment: go to the French Embassy and ask for another visa.

Answer (score 2):

If your visa is valid until June 8, unfortunately, you must leave the Schengen Area by June 8.

See http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/what-does-my-sticker-visa-mean

> Du:    (From:) Date from which you are allowed to enter the Schengen Area
>
> Au:    (To:) Date by which you **must leave** the Schengen Area
>
> These two dates specify the period for which your visa may be used (and not the length of stay allowed)